# runOnUiThread and callbacks strange behavior

Tags: java, android, callback

At runtime, I am using a callback pattern to have generic code run and use the callback when finished to execute code on the GUI.  So in my handler I use the runOnUiThread function against the callback.

These are all async http calls.  At runtime if I interrupt and use the back button and go to another fragment for example, the system will swap out the fragments and run both callbacks (the new fragment one on the correct callback, and the old callback that should have ran on the old fragment on the new current fragment).  This is wrong, the new fragment gets both callbacks but when it was initialized it was assigned to the other fragment...

This makes no sense and you can only observe the behavior by switching fragments at runtime before an async call finishes.  I don't see how it's possible, in the code I check if callback is null so it should have been garbage collected and how it runs on the new callback I don't know how it's possible....there's no additional assignment happening to change this.  It's almost like it's just looking in memory for the function signature and running it even though when it does it's on the wrong object.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on?  I've surpressed it with an ugly piece code, I just don't know how this is possible?

I understand the obvious candidates are if I assigned it again somewhere, but the answer is no.  When the fragment is created it creates an object, assigns itself as the callback, and processing begins so when the fragment is destroyed it should be too.  But the async task is still executing which is fine, why it does a callback on the new thread on the main gui I guess is because of runOnUiThread, so that function is somehow changing what the callback object points to in memory?

Comment: Without any piece of code posted it'll be really hard to help you for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Its your code :-)

There is no magic happening 'behind the scenes' in Android and no references are changed.

Many have problems like yours, and its always because they assume that the Android system is somehow cleaning up when a fragment or activity instance is replaced or removed. It isn't, and therefore the callbacks are still executed, on a obsolete fragment or activity.

runOnUiThread takes a Runnable and runs it when the UI thread have spare time (after invoking lifecycle methods and finished rendering). Its not magic either :-)

Comment: The only code I have is, new AsyncCall().setCallback(this).execute().  And in execute in the async call class it assigns the 'this' which is the fragment implementing Callback interface, the interface has an onComplete method.  In the fragment life cycle it's only created once at the beginning, not twice and never again.  Than when the fragment is swapped out of the navigation drawer container example it doesn't call the callback on the gone fragment...it calls it on the newly swapped in fragment.  I get what you're saying, but I just don't see where I'm making the mistake...

Comment: I'd have to see where you got the AsyncCall class from and some more code to be able to guess what is your problem